# How to override html without class or id

Tags: html, css, position

I'm trying to override a CSS attribute that is preventing me from centering a chart I have in a div.

I've seen lots of posts on these but not with importing a chart.

The chart I'm trying to center is from the google visualization API, but I should be able to solve this with just HTML and CSS.

Because the chart comes from Google, there is some code that I need to override, specifically a div that has `position: relative`

[image]

In the inspector, I can uncheck `position: relative` and the chart centers.

Problem is, I didn't write that code and when I try to override it like this:

```
    #electricalLineChart div div{
    position: static!important 
    }
```

It still favors the original position.

Here's the css:

```
#electricalLineChart{
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
}
```

Here's the html:

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
<table class="container">
    <tbody id="electrical-tables">
          <tr id="odd-cells">
          <td><div id="electricalLineChart"></div></td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I CANNOT use `align= "center"` in the HTML because it ruins the functionality of my chart.

Comment: Can you create a live example?, I tried to recreate the problem here https://codepen.io/dobladov/pen/OrdpBN?editors=1100 , but as you can see the CSS can override the style on the element

Comment: Found a solution, posted below. Thanks for offering the help.

Comment: In that case, don't forget that you can mark your own answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have other issues since setting a width and margin auto shouldn't be impacted by having `position: relative` on an element.

But, you probably need to increase the CSS selector specificity to override the incoming CSS. I would inspect the element with dev tools an copy the **FULL** CSS selector it displays. Then you need to **ADD** a tag to the hierarchy. Usually, you can do this by adding an ID to the body.

```
 #electricalLineChart div div{
    position: static!important 
    }
```

should become something like

```
 #mySite #electricalLineChart div div{
    position: static !important; 
    }
```

This makes your rule MORE SPECIFIC than the incoming CSS so yours will win.

Also make sure you have a space between the value and the ! as well as a ; at the end.

Comment: Hey Bryce, thanks for the input. Looks like when I apply !important that way, it doesn't work, I'll make an update

Comment: Yeah, that's why I don't think the positioning is the issue. Plus static and relative "Look" about the same. If you inspect it does the `position: static` get crossed out? or does it not appear at all? If its getting crossed out the other css is overriding yours. If its not crossed out then you have other CSS issues to look at.

Comment: Also now that I look at your code again. The width/margin code should be on the `.container` not `#electrical-tables`. A `tbody` has built in styling that makes them act funny so I'd work to position the wrapper the way you want it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, you definitely got me trying new things which lead me to a solution

Answer (score 1):

So stopped trying to override stuff because it wasn't working and literally just tried

```
#electricalLineChart{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
```

And it works now. 
Sometimes I just hate CSS.